# Agora cloud recording stop api always giving 404 response

Tags: node.js, api, live, agora.io, recording

[https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/${config.agoraAppId}/cloud_recording/resourceid/${meetingComplete.resourceId}/sid/${meetingComplete.sid}/mode/mix/stop](https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/$%7Bconfig.agoraAppId%7D/cloud_recording/resourceid/$%7BmeetingComplete.resourceId%7D/sid/$%7BmeetingComplete.sid%7D/mode/mix/stop) api getting below response always

```
 {
    resourceId: '',
    sid: '',
    code: 404,
    serverResponse: {
      command: 'StopCloudRecorder',
      payload: { message: 'Failed to find worker.' },
      subscribeModeBitmask: 1,
      vid: ''
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue due to s3 bucket region specified in agora cloud recording start api mismatching with s3 bucket region in aws.

Answer (score 2):

A `400` response from `stop` means your original request for `start` was properly formatted and successfully making the call to start the Agora Cloud Recorder instance but something caused the Agora Cloud Recorder worker to fail to start, so when you call stop there is nothing to stop because nothing actually started.

Have you tried using the [Agora Postman collection](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/6319646/SVSLr9AM) to test? I would recommend using it within Postman because it offers a working config that requires you to set your connection credentials into the variables and it should work if your bucket is properly configured.

[I wrote this quick-start guide](https://medium.com/agora-io/agora-cloud-recording-quickstart-guide-with-postman-demo-c4a6b824e708) on how to set up Cloud Recording and use the Postman collection to test that your storage bucket is properly configured.

Comment: The issue due to s3 bucket region specified in agora cloud recording start api mismatching with s3 bucket region in aws.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured out the issue. Is it working now?

Comment: yes, it working now. Thanks for the answer my question.